# how to solve: AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a problem with this code:

```
def get_lap(cmap):
    return scipy.sparse.csc_matrix(csgraph.laplacian(cmap, normed=False))

def fromcmaptocoords(C): 
    L = get_lap(C)
    eigw, eigv = LA.eigh(L.todense())
    vecs = eigv[:,1:3]
    guess_coords = pd.DataFrame(data=vecs, columns=["x", "y"])
    return guess_coords
```

I get the following error:

```
File "/Users/Sofia/Desktop/2d.py", line 102, in fromcmaptocoords
L = get_lap(C)

File "/Users/Sofia/Desktop/2d.py", line 96, in get_lap
 return scipy.sparse.csc_matrix(csgraph.laplacian(cmap, normed=False))

File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_laplacian.py",
line 69, in laplacian if csgraph.ndim != 2 or csgraph.shape[0] != csgraph.shape[1]:

AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

Could you help me with this? I don't know what I need to change
Thanks

Comment: What is the input you feed into `fromcmaptocoords`? Try `print(type(C))` in the first line of `fromcmaptocoords()`, what do you see?

Comment: Error tells you: `graph.laplacian(cmap, normed=False)` want's something that has a `ndim` attribute. You are giving it a `generator` instead, wich does not have it. - you probably need to feed it a [numpy.ndarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ndim.html)

Comment: uuuuh okay! thank you both! I'll try the two strategies!
The 'fromcmaptocoords' imput is a contact map so a square matrix with 0 or 1 as elements!